# django static and requirejs

Tags: django, requirejs

My SPA have a main page by starting url and registration page by /reg/ url. I use requirejs for get a static AMD chuck by chuck.
In main page I use 'static/' like a baseUrl. In registration page I use that too.
In django settings STATIC_URL = '/static/'.
So in registration page my static going by '/reg/static', not by '/static/' that I want.
What can I do? What I did not right?

Comment: did you specify the `STATIC_ROOT` ??

Comment: yeah, but it's not working. it's just get me all my static in a one directory. Im not correct?

Comment: exactly, the root is the place where all of your static files are located at. it should work

Comment: So. now Im in 'reg/' url and my static in 'static/'. But by this url my static wanna go by 'reg/static/'. Any way, static_root or not.

Comment: no! your static files should go with `/static/` only!

Comment: I know, but my browser don't think so. require.js:1952 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/landing/static/landing_page/js/app.js . static after landing.

Comment: the location of the static folder should be in the root next to the apps folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in requirejs.config. baseUrl include curent url, not a folder. So server get me a static not by path, by url. By the way I have to write correct url, in my case its '../static/'